# Running Python in Windows

Tags: python-3.x

Am new to python, i installed python 3.2 in my windows and tried the following code,

```
import urllib, urllister
usock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.net/")
parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(usock.read())
usock.close()
parser.close()
for url in parser.urls: print(url)
```

Its showing,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib, urllister
ImportError: No module named urllister
```

How to add that module?

Answer (score 3):

`urllister` is not part of the standard library.

You must download file `urllister.py` [from here](http://dev.gentoo.org/~dberkholz/articles/diveintopython-5.4/py/urllister.py), and save it next to the script you're running.